# Understanding dmesg warning

Tags: logs, dmesg, trace

Could anyone give some insight on what these warnings mean in the below dmesg log? Do they mean that the atl1c module is failing to load completely or merely a warning?

Any information that helps understanding the log better would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] WARNING: at kernel/irq/manage.c:1244 __free_irq+0xa7/0x200()
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Trying to free already-free IRQ 18
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Modules linked in: button ax88179_178a usbnet tg3 r8169 cnic bnx2 vmxnet3 pcnet32 e1000 sfc netxen_nic qlge qlcnic qla3xxx pch_gbe ptp_pch sky2 skge jme ipg uio alx atl1c atl1e atl1 libphy mii exfat(O) btrfs zlib_deflate hfsplus md4 hmac bnx2x(O) libcrc32c mdio mlx5_core(O) mlx4_en(O) mlx4_core(O) mlx_compat(O) compat(O) qede(O) qed(O) atlantic(O) r8168(O) tn40xx(O) i40e(O) ixgbe(O) be2net(O) igb(O) i2c_algo_bit e1000e(O) dca fuse vfat fat glue_helper lrw gf128mul ablk_helper sha512_generic arc4 cryptd ecryptfs sha256_generic sha1_generic ecb aes_x86_64 authenc des_generic ansi_cprng cts md5 cbc cpufreq_conservative cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_performance cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq mperf processor thermal_sys cpufreq_stats freq_table dm_snapshot
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  crc_itu_t crc_ccitt quota_v2 quota_tree psnap p8022 llc sit tunnel4 ip_tunnel ipv6 zram(C) sg etxhci_hcd mpt3sas mpt2sas(O) megaraid_sas ata_piix mptctl mptsas mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi megaraid megaraid_mbox megaraid_mm vmw_pvscsi BusLogic usb_storage xhci_hcd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_pci ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common el000(O)
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] CPU: 0 PID: 8840 Comm: ifconfig Tainted: P        WC O 3.10.102 #15266
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M4A78LT-M-LE, BIOS 0704    06/11/2010
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  ffffffff814a9ec3 ffffffff81032ee6 0000000000000000 ffff8800c74b3cf8
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  ffff8800caa4da80 0000000000000012 ffff8800caa4db0c ffffffff81032f47
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  ffffffff816f5e60 ffff880000000020 ffff8800c74b3d08 ffff8800c74b3cc8
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Call Trace:
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff814a9ec3>] ? dump_stack+0xc/0x15
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff81032ee6>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x56/0x70
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff81032f47>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x47/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aacc25>] ? atl1c_alloc_rx_buffer+0x385/0x410 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8109c837>] ? __free_irq+0xa7/0x200
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8109ca0f>] ? free_irq+0x2f/0xa0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aadddc>] ? atl1c_up+0x9c/0x190 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aab396>] ? atl1c_free_irq+0x16/0x40 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aae458>] ? atl1c_open+0x288/0x2e0 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813ef92e>] ? __dev_open+0x7e/0xe0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813efb81>] ? __dev_change_flags+0x91/0x140
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813efcb2>] ? dev_change_flags+0x12/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8144a12c>] ? devinet_ioctl+0x5fc/0x6c0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff810296e8>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1b8/0x480
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813d599b>] ? sock_do_ioctl+0x1b/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813d5dc8>] ? sock_ioctl+0x1d8/0x2a0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8110d0fe>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x20e/0x880
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff81238f86>] ? apparmor_cred_prepare+0x26/0x40
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff810f3417>] ? SyS_faccessat+0x197/0x2c0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8110d7f0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0xa0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff814afeb2>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] ---[ end trace 14fdad943159d686 ]---
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] WARNING: at kernel/irq/manage.c:1244 __free_irq+0xa7/0x200()
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Trying to free already-free IRQ 18
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Modules linked in: button ax88179_178a usbnet tg3 r8169 cnic bnx2 vmxnet3 pcnet32 e1000 sfc netxen_nic qlge qlcnic qla3xxx pch_gbe ptp_pch sky2 skge jme ipg uio alx atl1c atl1e atl1 libphy mii exfat(O) btrfs zlib_deflate hfsplus md4 hmac bnx2x(O) libcrc32c mdio mlx5_core(O) mlx4_en(O) mlx4_core(O) mlx_compat(O) compat(O) qede(O) qed(O) atlantic(O) r8168(O) tn40xx(O) i40e(O) ixgbe(O) be2net(O) igb(O) i2c_algo_bit e1000e(O) dca fuse vfat fat glue_helper lrw gf128mul ablk_helper sha512_generic arc4 cryptd ecryptfs sha256_generic sha1_generic ecb aes_x86_64 authenc des_generic ansi_cprng cts md5 cbc cpufreq_conservative cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_performance cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq mperf processor thermal_sys cpufreq_stats freq_table dm_snapshot
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  crc_itu_t crc_ccitt quota_v2 quota_tree psnap p8022 llc sit tunnel4 ip_tunnel ipv6 zram(C) sg etxhci_hcd mpt3sas mpt2sas(O) megaraid_sas ata_piix mptctl mptsas mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi megaraid megaraid_mbox megaraid_mm vmw_pvscsi BusLogic usb_storage xhci_hcd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_pci ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common el000(O)
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] CPU: 0 PID: 8840 Comm: ifconfig Tainted: P        WC O 3.10.102 #15266
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M4A78LT-M-LE, BIOS 0704    06/11/2010
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  ffffffff814a9ec3 ffffffff81032ee6 0000000000000000 ffff8800c74b3cf8
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  ffff8800caa4da80 0000000000000012 ffff8800caa4db0c ffffffff81032f47
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  ffffffff816f5e60 ffff880000000020 ffff8800c74b3d08 ffff8800c74b3cc8
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] Call Trace:
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff814a9ec3>] ? dump_stack+0xc/0x15
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff81032ee6>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x56/0x70
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff81032f47>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x47/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aacc25>] ? atl1c_alloc_rx_buffer+0x385/0x410 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8109c837>] ? __free_irq+0xa7/0x200
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8109ca0f>] ? free_irq+0x2f/0xa0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aadddc>] ? atl1c_up+0x9c/0x190 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aab396>] ? atl1c_free_irq+0x16/0x40 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aae458>] ? atl1c_open+0x288/0x2e0 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813ef92e>] ? __dev_open+0x7e/0xe0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813efb81>] ? __dev_change_flags+0x91/0x140
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813efcb2>] ? dev_change_flags+0x12/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8144a12c>] ? devinet_ioctl+0x5fc/0x6c0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813d599b>] ? sock_do_ioctl+0x1b/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff813d5dc8>] ? sock_ioctl+0x1d8/0x2a0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff810d57f1>] ? vma_rb_erase+0x121/0x260
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8110d0fe>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x20e/0x880
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff810d53ed>] ? remove_vma+0x4d/0x60
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff810d7399>] ? do_munmap+0x359/0x4d0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff8110d7f0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0xa0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018]  [<ffffffff814afeb2>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] ---[ end trace 14fdad943159d687 ]---
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:54 2018] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] WARNING: at kernel/irq/manage.c:1244 __free_irq+0xa7/0x200()
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] Trying to free already-free IRQ 18
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ip6table_filter ip6_tables xt_recent xt_iprange xt_limit xt_state xt_tcpudp xt_multiport xt_LOG nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables button ax88179_178a usbnet tg3 r8169 cnic bnx2 vmxnet3 pcnet32 e1000 sfc netxen_nic qlge qlcnic qla3xxx pch_gbe ptp_pch sky2 skge jme ipg uio alx atl1c atl1e atl1 libphy mii exfat(O) btrfs zlib_deflate hfsplus md4 hmac bnx2x(O) libcrc32c mdio mlx5_core(O) mlx4_en(O) mlx4_core(O) mlx_compat(O) compat(O) qede(O) qed(O) atlantic(O) r8168(O) tn40xx(O) i40e(O) ixgbe(O) be2net(O) igb(O) i2c_algo_bit e1000e(O) dca fuse vfat fat glue_helper lrw gf128mul ablk_helper sha512_generic arc4 cryptd ecryptfs sha256_generic sha1_generic ecb
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  aes_x86_64 authenc des_generic ansi_cprng cts md5 cbc cpufreq_conservative cpufreq_powersave cpufreq_performance cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq mperf processor thermal_sys cpufreq_stats freq_table dm_snapshot crc_itu_t crc_ccitt quota_v2 quota_tree psnap p8022 llc sit tunnel4 ip_tunnel ipv6 zram(C) sg etxhci_hcd mpt3sas mpt2sas(O) megaraid_sas ata_piix mptctl mptsas mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi megaraid megaraid_mbox megaraid_mm vmw_pvscsi BusLogic usb_storage xhci_hcd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_pci ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common el000(O)
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] CPU: 1 PID: 10035 Comm: ifconfig Tainted: P        WC O 3.10.102 #15266
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M4A78LT-M-LE, BIOS 0704    06/11/2010
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  ffffffff814a9ec3 ffffffff81032ee6 0000000000000000 ffff8800c97dbcf8
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  ffff8800caa4da80 0000000000000012 ffff8800caa4db0c ffffffff81032f47
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  ffffffff816f5e60 ffff880000000020 ffff8800c97dbd08 ffff8800c97dbcc8
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] Call Trace:
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff814a9ec3>] ? dump_stack+0xc/0x15
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff81032ee6>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x56/0x70
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff81032f47>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x47/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aacc25>] ? atl1c_alloc_rx_buffer+0x385/0x410 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff8109c837>] ? __free_irq+0xa7/0x200
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff8109ca0f>] ? free_irq+0x2f/0xa0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aadddc>] ? atl1c_up+0x9c/0x190 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aab396>] ? atl1c_free_irq+0x16/0x40 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffffa0aae458>] ? atl1c_open+0x288/0x2e0 [atl1c]
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff813ef92e>] ? __dev_open+0x7e/0xe0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff813efb81>] ? __dev_change_flags+0x91/0x140
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff813efcb2>] ? dev_change_flags+0x12/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff8144a12c>] ? devinet_ioctl+0x5fc/0x6c0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff810296e8>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1b8/0x480
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff813d599b>] ? sock_do_ioctl+0x1b/0x50
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff813d5dc8>] ? sock_ioctl+0x1d8/0x2a0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff8110d0fe>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x20e/0x880
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff81238f86>] ? apparmor_cred_prepare+0x26/0x40
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff810f3417>] ? SyS_faccessat+0x197/0x2c0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff8110d7f0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0xa0
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018]  [<ffffffff814afeb2>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[Wed Apr  4 19:51:55 2018] ---[ end trace 14fdad943159d688 ]---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This log is a warning from the kernel indicating there's probably a bug somewhere in the kernel code.

It's telling you that something is trying to free IRQ 18, even though it's already been freed before. As you have this repeatedly, it suggests something is trying to free it again and again.

The Comm: field shows it's while running the `ifconfig` command, in other words, configuring a network interface.

The call stack also indicates part of the code is in the `atl1c` kernel module, which I believe is used for the Atheros L1C Gigabit Ethernet, which is a network adapter.

So there seems to be enough correlation in there to suggest a bug somewhere in the driver for that device.

On the other hand, the kernel messsage is just a "WARNING", so it's possible that it's not really a bug (or a critical bug that would cause problems) but more of a problem with the design of the driver (maybe it's freeing the IRQ repeatedly for some reason...)

Searching for some of these terms in Google didn't really turn up much... So not sure if this is a know problem or not.

Kernel 3.10 is quite old... It's possible this has been fixed since, so maybe trying a newer kernel (if that's an option for you) might be a good idea.